# is there a way to make the second function use the first one: syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, react-final-form

```
export const composeValidators = (...validators) => value => validators.reduce((error, validator) => error || validator(value), undefined);

export const composeAccreditionValidators = (... validators) => value => validators.reduce((error, validator) => validator(value) === undefined ? error : `! ${validator(value)}`, undefined);
```

I am trying to create the second function exclusively for just one of my components and would prefer having the second one call the first one. Syntactically I may be making a few mistakes, and hence the code is blowing up on me. Can someone assist?

NOTE: I would like to keep the logic of the second one intact. Essentially it wraps the output string in a ! and a space unlike the first one.

---

Edit: Here are the same functions written, so they are easier to read.

```
function composeValidators(...validators) {
  return function (value) {
    return validators.reduce((error, validator) => (
      error || validator(value)
    ), undefined)
  }
}

function composeAccreditionValidators(...validators) {
  return function (value) {
    return validators.reduce((error, validator) => (
      validator(value) === undefined
        ? error
        : `! ${validator(value)}`
      ), undefined);
  }
}
```

Comment: I made some modifications to your example to try to understand what you were trying to do. After the edit, I am finding it hard to get it. Could you expand on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am trying to call the first function from the second one and wrap results of the second one in a space and exclamation mark if a error string is returned. Else return undefined.

Comment: @guzmonne I believe the objective is to make `composeAccreditionValidators` more DRY by reusing `composeValidators()`. I imagine that will require `composeValidators()`'s definition to be modified before that's possible though.

Comment: Yes that is correct @Patrick Roberts

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware, but the output format is not the only thing different between these two validator composers. The major difference is that the default composer calls each validator 0-1 times, and the "accredition" composer calls each validator 1-2 times. Is the amount of calls part of the behavior you wish to preserve? Also, do the validators ever return falsy values other than `undefined`? If the answer to both those questions is "no", then [muZk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57045023/1541563) should work, but otherwise it won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a function that composes both of these functions, and takes a curried `reducer` function as input:

```
const createComposeValidators = reducer => (...validators) => value =>
  validators.reduce(reducer(value), undefined)

export const composeValidators = createComposeValidators(
  value => (error, validator) =>
    error || validator(value)
)

export const composeAccreditionValidators = createComposeValidators(
  value => (error, validator) =>
    validator(value) === undefined ? error : `! ${validator(value)}`
)
```

Here is the same function written so it is easier to read:

```
function createComposeValidators(reducer) {
  return function composeValidators(...validators) {
    return function (value) {
      return validators.reduce(reducer(value), undefined)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use your `composeValidators` function in your `composeAccreditionValidators` function:

```
function composeValidators(...validators) {
  return function (value) {
    return validators.reduce((error, validator) => (
      error || validator(value)
    ), undefined)
  }
}

function composeAccreditionValidators(...validators) {
  const validate = composeValidators(...validators);
  return function (value) {
    const error = validate(value);
    return error && `! ${error}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that your `composeAccreditionValidators()` is functionally equivalent to the one in the question... for example, if any of the validators return a falsy value that isn't `undefined`, the default behavior you're relying on will behave differently than it should, and the accumulated `error` you get in your callback will not be what it needs to.

Comment: Another difference that's easier to verify is that the specialized behavior should be guaranteed to call every `validator()`, while the default behavior does not call the rest of the `validator()` functions after the first one that returns a truthy value.